# Run a kubectl port forward inside docker container fails

Tags: python-3.x, docker, kubectl, portforwarding

I want to run a command kubectl port-forward in a program, included in a container.

The code is as following:

```
list_pods = subprocess. \
        check_output(kub_props['get_pods'].format(**kwargs, **conf.config_data), shell=True).decode("utf-8")
    print(list_pods)
    pod_name = re.search(kub_props['re_pod_name'], list_pods).group(1)
    self.command = kub_props['port_forward'].format(pod_name=pod_name, **kwargs, **conf.config_data)
    print(self.command)
    self.sp: subprocess.Popen = subprocess.Popen(self.command.split(), shell=True)
```

Now, the situation is:
I always successfully get the list of pods (so kubernetes and kubectl are properly configured)

- If I run the python code directly in my Windows Session->OK
- If I run the command to port forward in a linux session ->OK
- If I run the program in my container->NOK.

Though, what is still weirder:
it seems that it doesn't understand the second cli, the one to port forward, and answer with the list of possible commands for kubectl
THEN, it displays the list of pods (print 1), THEN the command (print 2)
Thanks

Comment: You should almost definitely be using the [Kubernetes API](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) instead of trying to script `kubectl` commands.  You should _never_ create shell commands using string-formatting operations; it’s almost impossible to keep this secure, and in the setup you’re describing, a motivated attacker could collect information from any service running in your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You should almost definitely be using the [Kubernetes API](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) instead of trying to script kubectl commands. You should *never* create shell commands using string-formatting operations; it’s almost impossible to keep this secure, and in the setup you’re describing, a motivated attacker could collect information from any service running in your cluster.

Go to [Kubernetes Python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) github repository for examples.

Comment: Unfortunately, the kubernetes python client doesn't support port-forward: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/166